# codeigniter path issue

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to link my view page to another controller.

my test_view.php page

```
//this page address is base_url/controller1/function1
<a href='controller1/function2'> test </a>
```

If i click, the page address will be `base_url/controller1/function1/controller1/function2` which is not my desire.

my controller

```
   //the first function1 is to show my test_view page
    function function1 (){
       $this->load->view('test_view');
    }

   //I can't get to this function2 with the link I used
    function function2 (){
      $this->load->view('funny');
    }
```

Anyone could help me about this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure--you just need to tell CodeIgniter to display the path:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("controller1/function2");?>">
```

One thing: This displays the absolute path of your site as defined in your config, not the relative path.

I prefer relative paths, so I like to create a universal function called `site_path` to do the same thing without the absolute URL. I include it in one of my universally loaded libraries and it looks something like this:

```
function site_path($url) {
    return "/$url";
}
```

The benefit of this is that, if I initially develop the site in a subdirectory, I can set site_path to `return "/subdirectory/$url"` and then just remove the subdirectory once I launch.

Answer (score 2):

It's linking to a relative URL, you need to start with a '/' to use the web root

```
<a href='/controller1/function2'> test </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use following code in test_view.php page,
`<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>controller1/function2'> test </a>`